# how many unique ids can be generated

Tags: java, uuid

i am using the below code to create a unique Id which is 8 character (including numeric and alphanumeric characters).

```
try {
            List<String> uuidList = new ArrayList<String>();
            int counter = 1;
            File file = new File("D://temp//temp1.txt");
            file.createNewFile();

            Writer writer = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter wr = new  BufferedWriter(writer);
            while(true) {
                int length = bitsArray.length;
                Random r = new Random();
                StringBuffer uuid = new StringBuffer();
                for(int i= 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    int nextRandomId = r.nextInt(length);
                    uuid.append(bitsArray[nextRandomId]);
                }
                String uuidString = uuid.toString();
                wr.write(uuidString);
                wr.newLine();
                if(counter != 1 && uuidList.contains(uuidString)) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.err.println(counter);
                    break;
                }
                //061e735145fc
                System.err.println(uuidString);
                uuidList.add(uuidString);
                counter++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

i need to know, if i use the above code.. then how many unique ids i can generate. Given

```
static String[] bitsArray = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i",
                          "j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r",
                          "s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
                          "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
```

Please help..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In essence there is a **36<sup>8</sup>**  total strings you can generate.

This theorem is explained by using [Discrete Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_mathematics) (using Bit String):

You have 8 character bit string and you need to fill choose 1 out of 36 characters:

```
__  __  __  __  __  __  __  __  
36  36  36  36  36  36  36  36  (characters a -- z, 0-- 9)
```

Therefore you have `36*36*36*36*36*36*36*36` = 36<sup>8</sup>= `2,821,109,907,456` total id's.

Answer (score 2):

(26+10)^8 = 2 821 109 907 456

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here:

- http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html

Section `Permutations with Repetition`. In theory, given a set of `n` elements (i.e. length of your `bitsArray`) and the length of the permutation (i.e. your `uuidString` string) being `r`, you will be able to generate n^r unique permutations (i.e. UUIDs in your case).

In your case, n = 36 (26 letters and 10 numbers) and r = 8 (length of uuid is 8), so it's:

```
36^8 = 2821109907456
```

Answer (score 2):

**How many unique IDs?** About a million. It depends on the quality of the random number generator you are using. If that random number generator [always returns 4](http://xkcd.com/221/), you can only generate one identifier. If it's a low-quality linear congruential generator (that has pretty bad randomness for the lower bits) you could end up with 256 times fewer values than the theoretical maximum (which is 36<sup>8</sup> = about 2800 billion). However, since every ID you generate needs to read the entire list of previously generated IDs, I suspect your computer will just put itself out of its misery before it reaches one million identifiers.

**How many UUIDs?** Zero. Your code relies on an internal black list to avoid collisions, which means several computers generating UUIDs with your method have a fairly reasonable chance of ending up with a collision (avoiding that collision was the entire point of using UUIDs in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

`[number of possible char]^[lenght of the generatet id]` - very simple math

in your case:

`36^8 = 2821109907456`

Comment: Wrong.  Other way around.  If there are `n` possible characters, each character multiplies the number of possibilities by `n`.  Thus, the number of combinations is `n^[length of the generated id]`.

Comment: @luqui: isn't that exactly what i've wiritten (maybe you've written your comment while i edited my post, initially i wrote it wron like you said, but i corrected it almost instantly)

Answer (score -1):

the length of the array is 36. And you use the method `r.nextInt(length)`
it means that the max value of the random number is 36,from 0 to 35. so at most you can get 8 index 36.